# What does this statement means in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am not able to understand this statement. i already tired on google but this is showing up just as an example

```
$('#myDiv a:first').attr({
    href : 'newDestination.html',
    rel : 'super-special'
});
```

Comment: Set the attributes `href` and `rel` to the respective values for the first `<a>` element inside `#myDiv`. Go through jQuery tutorials and jQuery Docs.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its sets the attribute to a DOM element using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method of jquery.

In your example, you are setting `href` and `rel` attribute to an element which is matching the selector `'#myDiv a:first'`.

> '#myDiv a:first'

It means if there is a div with an id `myDiv`, it will take its first child element which is an anchor (`a`) and apply these attributes to it.